# Include Twig Template with Vars as another twig template

Tags: php, html, include, twig, extends

I have a twig template

**base.html.twig**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I have another twig template: **content.html.twig**

```
<div class="row">
    {{ content | raw }}
</div>
```

and an another one which is **box.html.twig**

```
<div class="col-md-{{ box.size|default(4) }} box-container">
    <div class="box {% if showBorder|default(true) == true %}border{% endif %} {{ box.color|default('red') }}">
        <div class="box-title">
            <h4><i class="{{ box.icon|default('fa fa-bars') }}"></i>{{ box.text }}</h4>

            <div class="tools">
                {% if showCollapseButton|default(true) == true %}
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if showCloseButton|default(false) == true %}
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="remove">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body {% if lightBody|default(false) == true %}bg{% endif %}">
            {% if showScroll|default(false) == true %}
                <div class="scroller" data-height="{{ scrollHeight|default(165) }}px">
                    {{ box.content|raw }}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                {{ box.content|raw }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the **working.html.twig** goes as

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

How do i get **box.html.twig** into **content.html.twig** and the final result in **working.html.twig**

I know i can get **content.html.twig** within **working.html.twig** as `{% include 'content.html.twig' with {'content':'Sample Content Here'} %}`

but how can i get **box.html.twig** into the *content* variable to pass to include **content.html.tiwg**

### Twig View is rendered as below:

```
twigLoader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(MVC_DIR);
        $twig = new Twig_Environment($twigLoader, array(
            'cache' => 'path/to/cache',
            'auto_reload' => true,
            'debug' => true,
        ));
        $this->twigCustomFunctions($twig);
echo $twig->render($viewPath, $this->viewVars);
```

Comment: Which framework are you using? In fact you can render the **box.html.twig** in your controller and pass the rendered values as `box.content`

Comment: @Javad, i am not using any framework. Just using Twig as my Templating engine.

Comment: Then you have to have some php code which render these twig files and pass the variables there (like `showCollapseButton`); could you provide some sample of your php side?

Comment: @Javad, showCollapseButton, showCloseButton, etc are variables which will be passed. I will make an edit in my question that shows how the twig template is rendered

Comment: Check my provided answer, hopefully helps you

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to render the box template first but set the rendered view to an array variable; then pass the variable to the content template
Something like this

```
$content = $twig->render('path/to/box.html.twig', array(...)); //pass the required variables for box.html instead of '...'
```

Now when you render the content.html you can pass the `$content`

```
echo $twig->render('path/to/content.html.twig', array(
    'content' => $content
));
```

Comment: Thanks @Javad, +1 for the answer, however, can this be done via Twig? just wondering if we could use `template_from_string` function of Twig. Just not getting the correct sequence of running on the code

Comment: I think you can do it by using `template_from_string` function but then you need to pass the same variable for the included template; but the point of `render` function is that it returns the rendered output as html string then you can just pass the rendered view as another string variable to the other template while rendering

Comment: You can also find more about `render` and its output on [http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html]